# Как решить ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'?

Tags: python, kivy

Показывает ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'

не могу понять почему? Открывает приложение, включает камеру, потом выключает почему то, вроде работает, но показывает ошибку, почему?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from requests import get
import requests


Window.size = (360, 480)
Window.clearcolor = (0, .17, .55, 1)


notice_list = []
department = 'kmd'


Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 5, 10
        spacing: 10

        Button:
            text: 'УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'ЗАКАЗЫ В РАБОТЕ'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'АРХИВ ЗАКАЗОВ'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'СКАНИРОВАНИЕ QR'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'

<ScanScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
    #:import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 5, 10
        spacing: 10

        ZBarCam:
            id: qrcodecam
        Label:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size[0], 50
            text: ' , '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in qrcodecam.symbols])

        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА НАЧАТА'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'start'
        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА ПРИОСТАНОВЛЕНА'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА ЗАКОНЧЕНА'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScanScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start = kwargs.get('start')

    def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = requests.post(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notice/{department}', data = {'user': department, 'id': notice_list})


def get_notice(_):
    for i in get(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notice/{department}').text.split(','):
        if i != '':
            notice_list.append(i)
    print(notice_list)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(ScanScreen(name='settings'))
        sm.add_widget(ScanScreen(name='start'))
        return sm


if __name__=='__main__':
    Clock.schedule_interval(get_notice, 1)

    MainApp().run()
```

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 148, in _update
    self._buffer = frame.reshape(-1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'
[ERROR  ] [OpenCV      ] Couldn't get image from Camera
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 144, in _update
    self._buffer = frame.imageData
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'imageData'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 148, in _update
    self._buffer = frame.reshape(-1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Comment: Нашел подобную проблему https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6736 Она не решена, но там была идея с `def on_leave(self, *args):`, где камера отключается. Думаю, нужно в этом направлении копать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде решили данную задачу:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from requests import get, post
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera

Window.size = (360, 480)
Window.clearcolor = (0, .17, .55, 1)


notice_list = []
department = 'kmd'


Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 5, 10
        spacing: 10

        Button:
            text: 'УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'ЗАКАЗЫ В РАБОТЕ'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'АРХИВ ЗАКАЗОВ'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'СКАНИРОВАНИЕ QR'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'

<ScanScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
    #:import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 5, 10
        spacing: 10

        ZBarCam:
            id: qrcodecam
        Label:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size[0], 50
            text: ' , '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in qrcodecam.symbols])

        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА НАЧАТА'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
            on_press: app.start()
        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА ПРИОСТАНОВЛЕНА'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА ЗАКОНЧЕНА'
            background_color: 0, .12, .52, 1
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScanScreen(Screen):
    pass


def get_notice(_):
    for i in get(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notice/{department}').text.split(','):
        if i != '':
            notice_list.append(i)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(ScanScreen(name='settings'))
        return sm

    def start(self):
        r = get(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/give_csrf')
        csrf = r.text.split('=')[-1][1:-2]
        cookies = r.cookies.get_dict()

        post(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/qr_start/{department}',
              data = {'id': notice_list, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf},
              cookies = cookies)


if __name__=='__main__':
    Clock.schedule_interval(get_notice, 3)

    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Насколько я вижу, Вы перенесли функцию `start` из `ScanScreen` в `MainApp`, верно? Можете ли Вы чуть подробнее описать действия, которые привели к решению данной проблемы, а также закрыть вопрос, отметив этот ответ как верный (галочка слева)?